# Armadillo generates the same random numbers

Tags: random, armadillo

I generate a matrix with randoms using Armadillo package (v.7.300.1) under cygwin64 (or minGW):

```
#include<armadillo>

int main(){
  arma::mat(3,3, arma::fill::randu).print();
  return 0;
}
```

The program (after re-build or re-run) always generates:

```
0.6900  0.5548  0.2074    
0.5054  0.3784  0.6263    
0.5915  0.2577  0.3401
```

Why is it always the same? What's wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to set the seed *to introduce randomness*.  Recall that all (Q)RNGs are deterministic.  What you see here, Conrad would call a feature.

From the docs:

> To change the RNG seed, use `arma_rng::set_seed(value)` or `arma_rng::set_seed_random()` functions.

#### Demo

A slightly repaired version of your file:

```
/tmp$ cat armaRand.cpp 
#include<armadillo>

int main(){
  arma::arma_rng::set_seed_random();
  arma::mat(3,3, arma::fill::randu).print();
  exit(0);
}
/tmp$ g++ -o armaRand armaRand.cpp 
/tmp$ ./armaRand 
   0.8824   0.4457   0.3589
   0.7134   0.4768   0.8335
   0.0171   0.4119   0.3720
/tmp$ ./armaRand 
   0.3417   0.3643   0.6865
   0.2814   0.0191   0.6797
   0.9737   0.1593   0.5013
/tmp$
```

If you want *reproducible results* you want to use the other variant and keep track of the seed *value*.

*Edit:* In late 2018 with newer version of Armadillo, linking appears now to be required so please make it `g++ -o armaRand armaRand.cpp -larmadillo`. The rest still holds: by *seeding* the random number generator with (sufficiently) random bits we do get different answers as expected.

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow.  If the answer helps, please "upvote it" (click on up-triangle) and maybe "accept it" (click on tickmark only you as OP see).  That;s how it works around here ...

Comment: Hey! When I run the command I get this error: **/tmp/ccw92UPB.o: In function `TLS wrapper function for arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance':
test.cpp:(.text._ZTWN4arma23arma_rng_cxx11_instanceE[_ZTWN4arma23arma_rng_cxx11_instanceE]+0x21): undefined reference to `arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

Comment: I am forced to use Armadillo v3. Any idea to set the seed there? `set_seed_random` doesnt seem to exist and I cannot find docs for v3

Comment: I guess you'll have to poke through the headers of that version then.